# Setting CSS from javascript events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting started with javascript and I'm trying to do a simple example but changing the CSS of a div based on the onmouseover and onmouseout of the div element.

My test is to create a green box. When I mouse over it it should turn blue. When I mouse out it should go back to green.

Here is my source:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<style>
    #box {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setBlue(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.background-color = "blue";
}

function setGreen(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.background-color = "green";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box" onmouseover="setBlue()" onmouseout="setGreen()" />
</body>
</html>
```

When the pages loads the green box shows but when I mouse over nothing happens.

Comment: Change `background-color` in your functions to `backgroundColor`.

Comment: I tried changing background-color to backgroundColor in my javascript functions but still no change.

Comment: you can run the code snippet of the answer proposed by Moogs below, and you will see it does work.

Comment: Using backgroundColor did work. The problem(as shown in Moogs answer below) was using a global variable for the div element. Not sure why that didn't work.

Comment: @Sebas:  Since these events are declared inline, `this` would refer to the window object within each function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style.background-color` should be `style.backgroundColor`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <style>
    #box {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function setBlue() {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }

    function setGreen() {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="box" onmouseover="setBlue()" onmouseout="setGreen()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Just wondering, any idea why I couldn't use a global variable for the element and use the global variable in both functions?

Comment: @James probably because you are not waiting for the content to be loaded, otherwise the element will be undefined because scripts on the head are executed before the body loads. Use DOMContentLoaded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @James:  If you move your <script> code after </body>, it will be able to access your DOM content.  Alternatively (and this is best practice), move your JavaScript to a separate file.

Comment: @Moogs Thanks, I get it. Setting the variable after loading did the trick.

Comment: @RickHitchcock That makes sense. As for the separate JavaScript file that is probably what I would do in a real page. This was just to increase my knowledge for how JavaScript works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `style` alone:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.example       { background-color:green; }
.example:hover { background-color:blue;  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<span class='example'>Hallo World</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My purpose was to see how to do it with JavaScript to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead "-" upper signal

```
document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using the # sign when you are referencing an id, like so:

```
document.getElementById("#box").style.background-color = "blue";
```

Comment: Regardless of the `#` sign which I'm not even sure whether itwould work, you don't address the principal issue which is the javascript notation difference for css style assignments

Comment: `style.background-color` should be `style.backgroundColor`

Comment: @Sebas The reason why it is not going blue, could well be that the # sign is missing

Comment: The # sign is jQuery syntax.  It won't work in JavaScript.  `$('#box')[0]` in jQuery is equivalent to `document.getElementById('box')` in vanilla JavaScript.